# Datastax Bulk Loader can't find my SSL certificate

Tags: cassandra, dsbulk

On my windows machine I have CQLSH working and using a .cert file
Now I am starting to use DSBulk, but can't get the command line to know where to find my certificate.
I have a cert file here:  C:\myfolder\mycert.cer

Here is a sample of my command line:
dsbulk count --ssl -u "myusername" -p "mypassword" -h "123.12.123.12" -k "mykeyspace" -query "select count(*) from mytable;"

the error message:
Operation failed: Expecting long or short option, got: 'myusername'

I suspect that I need to modify my command parameters to reference the cert file.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just open DSBulk documentation - it has all information: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

@John O'Sullivan

According to the documentation idea shared above by Alex, you need to feed a file to the dsbulk command:

```
dsbulk {
   connector.name = "csv"
   connector.csv.delimiter = "|"
   schema.keyspace = "myKeyspace"
   schema.table = "myTable"
   schema.mapping = "0=name, 1=age, 2=email" 
}   

datastax-java-driver {
  advanced {
    ssl-engine-factory {
      keystore-password = "cassandra"
      keystore-path = "/Users/myaccount/tmp/ssl/keystore.node0"
      class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
      truststore-password = "dse#r0cks!"
      truststore-path = "/Users/myaccount/tmp/ssl/truststore.node0"
    }
  }
}
```

Then the command line references the file:

```
dsbulk load -f my-application.conf -url file1.csv -k ks1 -t table1
```

The specific page you need to reference is:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkUseSsl.html